# PHP Smarty: unable to define templates dir

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

I'm using php 7.2 and smarty-3.1.30 and I'm using the quick install tutorial from here:
https://www.smarty.net/quick_install

My *test_template.php*:

```
<?php
require('/var/www/html/include/smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php');
$smarty = new Smarty();
//ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$smarty->setTemplateDir('/var/www/html/smarty/templates');
$smarty->setCompileDir('/var/www/html/smarty/templates_c');
$smarty->setCacheDir('/var/www/html/smarty/cache');
$smarty->setConfigDir('/var/www/html/smarty/configs');

$smarty->testInstall();

$smarty->assign('name', 'Ned');
$smarty->display('index.tpl');
```

the result is:

```
Smarty Installation test...
Testing template directory...
/var/www/html is OK.
Testing compile directory...
FAILED: /var/www/html is not writable.
Testing plugins directory...
/var/www/html is OK.
WARNING: Smarty's own libs/plugins is not available.
Testing cache directory...
FAILED: /var/www/html is not writable.
Testing configs directory...
FAILED:  does not exist.
Testing sysplugin files...
... OK
Testing plugin files...
... OK
Tests complete.
```

when enable the debug I get:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty: Unable to load template 'file:index.tpl' <-- thrown in /var/www/html/include/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php on line 163
```

no matter what I try, the template dir is always set to **/var/www/html** I'm not sure what is happening. I'm certainly sure the those paths exist and the permission is set to 777.[image]

im using centos 7 with apache+php 7. selinux is disabled

please help me.

Comment: Do all these directories exist?

Comment: OK i found the problem. its caused by php 7.2, downgrade to 7.1 work fine